# How to set what columns are shown in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

The columns shown in Windows directories vary according to the type of contents.
I would like to show only the name, date modified, attributes, size and type, GLOBALLY (for all drives) and permanently. How to do that?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-can-i-change-the-default-order-of-files-as/0df1c9a2-0803-4bcc-90e4-137c5ed09049

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 File Explorer, right click on Name or other column, use the Pull Down to set columns that you wish to see.

Then, still in File Explorer, View Tab, Options and a new Dialog Window comes up titled Folder Options. Click on View tab and then Apply to Folders button.

This works but may need to be done from time to time. File Explorer has a mind of its own

For rigorous settings that can be saved, consider xPlorer2 (Zabkat.com)

[image]

I managed to capture the column options by going to the next step

[image]

Comment: I already had figured that out, and also that it's NOT a permanent solution and NOT globally applied. So, this is not the answer I'm seeking.

Comment: You can do the setting when needed, or as I offered consider a more permanent third party solution. I use File Explorer as well and it does an OK job of keeping settings.

Comment: It only applies the settings permanently for the given folder... which is useless. Using a third-party solution is not the way to go as future Microsoft updates might break this easily.

Comment: If you do Apply to All from the top level Windows folder it works a lot better.

Comment: It does not do what I want - GLOBALLY and PERMANENTLY. I don't mind tweaking the registry if it can be done from there.

Comment: I've done this before, let me look for it....what icon mode? Details???

Comment: There is no setting in Windows Explorer to make changes permanently. If you really need that (I benefit from this) use xPlorer2 - it works better.

Comment: The link I posted explains what to do AND WHAT ORDER to do it in to achieve your goal. It simple when you understand it.

Answer (score 2):

The `.reg` file exceeds character limit for this site, so use the follwowing **PowerShell** *to create the .reg file*. Just edit the path in the first line, then copy the entire code block & paste in PowerShell console. Then right-click the newly-created file & select `Merge`. Sign out & sign back in. This clobbers everything, incluidng Search Results.

```
$RegFile = 'c:\<valid path here>\AllFolders-SameColumns.reg'
$File = @'
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]

'@ # File

$Prepend = '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\'
$Append  = @'
]
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"FFlags"=dword:41000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,05,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,2d,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,b8,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0d,00,00,00,66,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,\
  f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,5a,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,\
  02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,04,00,00,00,fc,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000


'@ # $Append

@'
{0b0ba2e3-405f-415e-a6ee-cad625207853}
{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5}
{24ccb8a6-c45a-477d-b940-3382b9225668}
{292108be-88ab-4f33-9a26-7748e62e37ad}
{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788}
{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b}
{3f98a740-839c-4af7-8c36-5badfb33d5fd}
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}
{4F01EBC5-2385-41f2-A28E-2C5C91FB56E0}
{51294DA1-D7B1-485b-9E9A-17CFFE33E187}
{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D}
{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}
{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49}
{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8}
{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed}
{672ECD7E-AF04-4399-875C-0290845B6247}
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3}
{71D642A9-F2B1-42cd-AD92-EB9300C7CC0A}
{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656}
{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943}
{834d8a44-0974-4ed6-866e-f203d80b3810}
{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}
{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78}
{978e0ed7-92d6-4cec-9b59-3135b9c49ccf}
{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}
{c1f8339f-f312-4c97-b1c6-ecdf5910c5c0}
{C4D98F09-6124-4fe0-9942-826416082DA9}
{CD0FC69B-71E2-46e5-9690-5BCD9F57AAB3}
{da3f6866-35fe-4229-821a-26553a67fc18}
{db2a5d8f-06e6-4007-aba6-af877d526ea6}
{DD61BD66-70E8-48dd-9655-65C5E1AAC2D1}
{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b}
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4}
{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9}
'@ -split "`n" | ForEach{
     $File += "$Prepend$_$Append"
}

$File | Set-Content $RegFile
```

To undo, delete the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

### Alternate code

Run the following from an ***Admin*** **PowerShell** console. Creates & merges the .reg file:

```
$RegFile = "$Env:Temp\AllFolders-SameColumns.reg"
$File = @"
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`n
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults]`n
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU]`n
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]`n
"@ # File

$Prepend = '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\'
$Append  = @"
]
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"FFlags"=dword:41000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,05,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,2d,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,b8,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0d,00,00,00,66,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,\
  f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,5a,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,\
  02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,04,00,00,00,fc,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000`n`n
"@ # $Append

$FT      = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
$Include = 'Documents|Downloads|Generic|Home|Music|Pictures|Searches|UserFiles|UsersLibraries|Videos'

gci $FT | Get-ItemProperty | 
   ? CanonicalName -match $Include | Select -expand PSChildName |
ForEach{
   $File += "$Prepend$_$Append"
}
$File | Set-Content $RegFile
Reg import $RegFile

#######
# Undo [-HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]
```